# How can I select a specific text from below code?

Tags: javascript

In below code, What is the variable name of "Senior Information Security Consultant" string?
I want to write an "if" condition that if the variable equal this string then print an output.

```
<a data-control-name="pymk_profile" href="/in/Example-4a393356/" id="ember136" class="discover-person-card__link ember-view">      <span class="visually-hidden">Member’s name</span>
          <span class="discover-person-card__name t-16 t-black t-bold">
            Example
          </span>

      <span class="visually-hidden">Member’s occupation</span>
      <span class="discover-person-card__occupation t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        Senior Information Security Consultant | Speaker | Author
      </span>
</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code to the question to create a [mcve]. If the link is deleted or modified, this question stands useless

Comment: Do not paste links to code. **Always** put the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to select the  element:

```
document.querySelector('.discover-person-card__occupation .t-14 .t-black--light .t-normal');
```

Then, access the "textContent" attribute:

```
.textContent;
```

combined:

```
document.querySelector('.discover-person-card__occupation .t-14 .t-black--light .t-normal').textContent;
```

The result will be a string for you to use.

EDIT:
Now you can manipulate the string, using the String.prototype.split method.
For example:

```
str.split(' ');
```

Will split the string by SPACE and save each fraction to a cell inside of an array.

Comment: it will give the full text `Senior Information Security Consultant | Speaker | Author`, isn't it

Comment: Thank you. I saw a code that click on "connect" button on Linkedin.com automatically. I want to change it and click on "connect" button by skill or location. It is a very small code. Can I share it?

Answer (score 0):

## update

If you don't prefer to use jQuery, then try this:

```
var fullText=document.getElementsByClassName("discover-person-card__occupation")[0].textContent;
var resultText=fullText.split("|")[0];
console.log(resultText);
```

Using `jQuery`, you can do this:

```
var fullText=$("span.discover-person-card__occupation").text();
var resultText=fullText.split("|")[0];
console.log(resultText);
```

Comment: Thbis question is not tagged [tag:jquery].

Comment: @connexo, okk. that's why I said using jquery, if he prefers. Btw, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.querySelector` you can get the occupation string to a variable named `occupation` in this example.

```
const occupation = document.querySelector('.discover-person-card__occupation').textContent;
```

If you want to compare that occupation exactly with the string `Senior Information Security Consultant`

```js
document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'none';

const searchValue = 'Senior Information Security Consultant';
const occupation = document.querySelector('.discover-person-card__occupation').textContent;
occupation === searchValue && (document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'block')
```

```html
<a data-control-name="pymk_profile" href="/in/Example-4a393356/" id="ember136" class="discover-person-card__link ember-view">      <span class="visually-hidden">Member’s name</span>
    <span class="discover-person-card__name t-16 t-black t-bold">
            Example
          </span>

    <span class="visually-hidden">Member’s occupation</span>
    <span class="discover-person-card__occupation t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        Senior Information Security Consultant | Speaker | Author
      </span>
</a>

<span id="message">Show your message</span>
```

Again if you want to check the existence of the `Senior Information Security Consultant` in your `occupation` string, can use `indexOf()`

```js
document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'none';

const searchValue = 'Senior Information Security Consultant';
const occupation = document.querySelector('.discover-person-card__occupation').textContent;

occupation.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1 && (document.getElementById("message").style.display = 'block')
```

```html
<a data-control-name="pymk_profile" href="/in/Example-4a393356/" id="ember136" class="discover-person-card__link ember-view">      <span class="visually-hidden">Member’s name</span>
    <span class="discover-person-card__name t-16 t-black t-bold">
            Example
          </span>

    <span class="visually-hidden">Member’s occupation</span>
    <span class="discover-person-card__occupation t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        Senior Information Security Consultant | Speaker | Author
      </span>
</a>

<span id="message">Show your message</span>
```

If you want to make it case insensitive comparison then can convert the string to lower or upper case. Example:

```
const searchValue = 'Senior Information Security Consultant'.toLowerCase();
const occupation = document.querySelector('.discover-person-card__occupation').textContent.toLowerCase();
```